# Great Circle distance plus altitude change

Tags: geometry, geospatial

How do you exactly compute the distance traveled between two points at different altitudes on a spherical body? If the two points are at the same altitude it's a simple great-circle calculation. But what is the additional term to account for a steady climb or descent precisely? Say we're talking about a spaceplane that steadily climbs up to a great height over a great distance after taking off.

Illustration: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n7jL.png

Comment: The best idea I have at the moment is to fit a second degree polynomial to the end points and a midpoint at half-way up in altitude. Then integrate to compute the length of the segment of the ellipse. I think this would be an approximation because the rate of climb/descent wouldn't be modeled quite right.

Comment: What do you know about the climb and descent?

Comment: The rate of climb/descent is constant over the entire segment length being considered.

Comment: If the speed is also constant you'll end up with a triangle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The National Geodetic Survey (NGS) (a division of NOAA) has some information on this, and even sample Fortran code and working programs on their website and for a PC.

See:
http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/Inv_Fwd/Inv_Fwd.html

The program that you want is INVERS3D:
http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/

You will need to look through their code for specifics, but they calculate "ellipsoidal distance, the mark-to-mark distance, and the ellipsoid height difference" using lat/long/altitude.

From their website:

> **INVERS3D**
>
> Program INVERS3D is the three dimensional version of program INVERSE,
>   and is the tool for computing not just the geodetic azimuth and
>   ellipsoidal distance, but also the mark-to-mark distance, the
>   ellipsoid height difference, the DX, DY, DZ (differential X, Y, Z used
>   to express GPS vectors), and the DN, DE, DU (differential North, East,
>   Up using the FROM station as the origin of the NEU-coordinate system).
>   The program requires geodetic coordinates as input, expressed as
>   either: 1) latitude and longitude in degrees, minutes, and seconds or
>   decimal degrees along with the ellipsoid heights for both stations, or
>   2) rectangular coordinates (X, Y, Z in the Conventional Terrestrial
>   Reference System) for each station. The program works exclusively on
>   the GRS80 ellipsoid and the units are meters. Both types of
>   coordinates may be used in the same computation. The program reads
>   input geodetic positions with the default hemispheres for latitude and
>   longitude set at North and West.